# Ubuntu run out of space

Tags: ubuntu, debugging

I installed Ubuntu 19 on my desktop on 220GB HDD, because my previous installation run out of space. I was loosing gigabites every minute, so I figured out that I will install the newest version.

Week later, yesterday, I checked remaining space. Out of 220 I had only 100GB free.
I have installed only two games (XCOM2 & HOI4 = 40GB), I had installed phpstorm and docker. That is that (maybe some office communicator and such)

Then, during the night while I was watching movie (John Wick finally), the system told me that it is running out of space.

There was literally 0 bytes free. 
Thrash was empty, I have not doing anything and my free space was just gone.
Now I am unable to boot into the ubuntu - I am stuck with a black screen.

So my questions are:
1) wtf is going on? Why my system loose more than 150GB in day?
2) how can I debug it? I used Ubuntu because I hoped that such a BS would never happen...
3) Is it because of steam? I would say that the system works fine until I install it... But why would that be connected? 
4) Also it was said that Ubuntu works badly with Xcom2, so I wonder which linux distribution can handle it correctly... I assume that docker can work everywhere, so I will probably reinstall.

Finally I would like to thank you in advance with this. I am really repressed because I didnt git push my work. Again.

Comment: Also I would say that this is on my desktop computer.
I have very the same thinks on my laptop and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've said you have docker, maybe you should cleanup docker repository since every image can occupy a lot of space on disk.

```
// To see the list of images
docker images 

// to remove images
docker rmi  <IMAGE_ID>
```

Another useful command can be:

```
du -h --max-depth=1
```

Try this command starting from root and you'll see which folder(s) occupy a lot of space on disk.

You can also try to analyze with some interval to see where were the changes.

P.S. I can't comment on the Gaming part of this question, in general Stack Overflow is for concrete programming questions and issues usually with source code. So maybe you should try another forum/place...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer... I assume I have to boot via rescue mode to do such a think..
So every time I run docker-compose up it creates new image and doesnt delete the old one? I assume there is a way that it clears the repository automatically then?
Thanks for the gaming part... I see, I thouth that it might be connected to the problem, I didnt suspect docker being the root of the evil here...

Comment: You don't need any rescue mode. Being a root is enough (because you want to be able to access the folder structure and not run into issue of lack of permissions)

Comment: Also it is strange to me that laptop is fine with the same setup and there is no free disk space missing... Never mind, lets try the clearing...

Comment: The problem is that I cannot boot into the system. I have a black screen after I insert "unlock HDD" password...

Comment: since docker's images are files like anything else, but invoking du -h command you'll be able to track the folder that takes up much place... As for docker compose part, it really depends on what's written there. It can build images or reuse existing...

Comment: Ou yeah... So it is clear now... Docker images command showed up that images takes like 150 MB ... BUT the second command lured me into STEAM FOLDER WHICH HAS 190 GB!!!!!! Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for anyone interested why is their disk space missing on Ubuntu - go to the steam folder and check ERROR.LOG ...
Main was about 180GB...